# Find all numbers that are their own multiplicative inverse in mod p where p is prime.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

> Find all numbers that are their own multiplicative inverse in $mod$ $p$ where $p$ is prime.

I recall that when $p$ is prime, all integers from 1 to the modulus minus 1, so all numbers from $1$ to $p-1$, have multiplicative inverses in mod $p$. So, the numbers that are their own multiplicative inverse would be $1$ and $1-p$. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: We have $a \equiv a^{-1} \mod p$. If you multiply both sides by $a$ we get $a^2 \equiv 1 \mod p$. This solves as $(a + 1)(a - 1) \equiv 0 \mod p$.

Comment: @orlp: And then use fact that p is prime to argue $(a+1)(a-1)=0$ has only two solutions $mod p $ , since $\mathbb Z_p$ is a field, so an integral domain.

Comment: @orlp how did you infer $a≡a^{−1}\pmod{p}$?

Comment: @mehsheenman That's the premise of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You want to solve $x^2=1$ i.e. $(x-1)(x+1)=0$, which for a prime modulus gives $x=\pm 1$.